# ES6: Shorten repetitive getters

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Is the way to short this piece of JS-code?
Maybe symbols may be useful? ES6+

```
class Instance {
  // ...
  static get value() {
    return wrapper('value')
  }

  get value() {
    return secondWrapper(Instance.value);
  }

  getValue() {
    return thirdWrapper(this.value);
  }
  // ...
}
```

I don't want to modify way of calling because of convention. But the file becomes larger and larger. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you'd like to shorten here. Those are three different methods doing three different things, not much duplication between them (they all use different wrappers). Do you have to repeat the whole pattern multiple times, or where is the problem?

Comment: All getters should be reachable outside the class scope. There are a lot of instances, wrappers are also different.

Comment: What do you mean by "*reachable outside the class scope*"? `class` syntax doesn't introduce a scope. Sure, you can access only the static getter without an instance, but you can use the other getters on any instance, regardless of how many instances there are.

Comment: Maybe you'll want to post a whole file so that we can see how exactly it becomes "larger and larger".

Answer (score 0):

```
getValue(){
  return third(second (firstWrapper('value')));
}
```

Comment: Tis' impracticable due the convention. All getters should be reachable outside the class scope. Any ideas?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.